# Java project structure: module dependencies in sources vs binaries

Tags: java, dependencies, project-management

I've seen projects where one single project divided into modules, and each module is maven project itself. These modules integrated through one module which contains references to all other modules. To launch project user must import all modules in IDE. So, why people using this approach? Isn't much easier to package all modules to jar and include as dependencies to some module? Is there any benefit to use projects instead jars? Drawbacks of using projects are: user needs to keep all modules in IDE, may accidentally change source code, and if IDE starts to compile all that modules it takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you accidentally change one file, only this file gets recompiled, that's not a big deal.

Usually, you need to modularize your project to cut interdependencies and make everything more controllable. Often, the parent project doesn't even have any source files of its own; instead, it is only used to aggregate the modules. Modules are just used here to separate a big project into pieces.

You could develop those pieces as separate projects, but to implement a change in one module and make it available for other modules that use it, you'd have to build that module and actualize a dependency in the client module. That's cumbersome. It's much more practical to keep them as one big project where you just change the code you need to change, and it's available to all the modules that depend on it.